# How to Allocate Array Values for every iteration in while loop

Tags: php, angularjs

```
    $data1 = array();
    $final_ttt = "15";
    $items = [];
    for ($j = 1; $j <= $final_ttt; ++$j)
    {
    $TeamNo = "t$j";
    $items[] = $TeamNo;
    }
    print_r($items);

    In while loop im getting below values

    $day = 1;
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $qry->fetch()) 
    {
        $name = $row['name'];   //a,b,c,d
        $loopvalue = $row['loopvalue']; // getting 2,3,8,3,4

        $data1[]=array("name" => $name,"loopvalue" => $loopvalue);

        if( $i % $final_ttt == 0 )
        {
            $fday = "Day ".$day;
            $day++;
        }
    }

    output
name    value   Team                            day
a       2       t1,t12                          1
b       3       t3,t4,t5                        1           
c       8       t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12      1
d       3       t13,t14,t15                     1
e       4       t1,t2,t3,t4                     2
```

How to allocate the teams to based on while loop value. if i get value is 2 => then i need to allocate first 2 teams t1,t2 like this. kinldy help me.

Thanks you in advance

--- We are editing the question as the solution provided does not work in certain test cases. Like the one shown in the attached image.

[image]

Here is the updated code for above image output

```
$lastIndex = 0;
$day = 1;
while($row = $qry->fetch()) 
{
    $name = $row['name'];   //a,b,c,d
    $loopvalue = $row['loopvalue']; // getting 2,3,8,3,4

    if($i==0)
    {
        $fday = "Day ".$day;//Day 1 for first Itration
        $day = 2;
    }

    $team = implode(',',array_slice($items, $lastIndex, $loopvalue));
    $lastIndex = $lastIndex + $loopvalue;

    if($lastIndex > count($items))
    {
        $lastIndex = $lastIndex - count($items);
        $team .= ','.implode(',',array_slice($items, 0, $lastIndex));

        $fday = "Day ".$day;
        $day++;
    }
    $data1[]=array("name" => $name,"loopvalue" => $loopvalue, "day" => $fday, 'team' => $team);
    $row ++;
}
print_r($data1);
```

Comment: Are last two outputs are correct `d       3       t13,t14,t15
                                                    e       4       t1,t2,t3,t4` ??  Don't you think last row should have  `e       4       t16,t17,t18,t19` ??

Comment: **_then i need to allocate first 2 teams_** allocate?? to whom?? unclear

Comment: @YashParekh to name-a => first two teams t1,t2, next name-b => further teams t3,t4,t5 based on values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like below

```
$lastIndex = 0;
while($row = $qry->fetch()) 
{
    $name = $row['name'];   //a,b,c,d
    $loopvalue = $row['loopvalue']; // getting 2,3,8,3,4

      $team = implode(',',array_slice($items, $lastIndex, $loopvalue));
      $lastIndex = $lastIndex + $loopvalue;
      if($lastIndex > count($items)) {
          $lastIndex = $lastIndex - count($items);
          $team .= ','.implode(',',array_slice($items, 0, $lastIndex));
       }    

        $data1[]=array("name" => $name,"loopvalue" => $loopvalue, 'team' => $team);
     $row ++;
    }

print_r($data1);
```

Will result like

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => a [loopvalue] => 2 [team] => t1,t2 ) [1] => Array ( [name] => b [loopvalue] => 3 [team] => t3,t4,t5 ) [2] => Array ( [name] => c [loopvalue] => 8 [team] => t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12,t13 ) [3] => Array ( [name] => d [loopvalue] => 3 [team] => t14,t15,t1 ) [4] => Array ( [name] => e [loopvalue] => 4 [team] => t2,t3,t4,t5 ) )
```

Let me know if this solve your problem.

Comment: Above code does not work on Day5, here you can see T9,T10 are allocated twice on the same day (i.e Day5). A single team cannot be at 2 different places on the same day. Kindly advice how this problem can be avoided. **Please check the updated question**

Comment: @konda As per your question  **if i get value is 2 => then i need to allocate first 2 teams t1,t2 like this and so on** . So based upon that i answered. The above answer only takes **value** into consideration not **day**. So if value is 2 then it will show t1,t2  and next value is 3 then it will show t3,t4,t5 and so on. So please make sure what do you need before asking question. As nowhere in question it was asked to get output based upon **day**.